Does centripetal force cause compressive force?
Let’s assume there is a perfect circular rigid body with radius
 rotating about the center of the circle. As we move farther from the center along the radius of this body, the centripetal force increases. Since the centripetal force always points toward the center of rotation, the outer parts of the rigid body experience a greater centripetal force than the inner parts. Given that it is a rigid body, the structure and internal stresses will maintain the circular shape. The question is whether there are internal forces acting within the body, and if they exist, whether they are compressive or tensile.

The overall stresses are tensile. But you could build shapes that would put parts of the structure in compression, shear, bending, or torsion.

How can compressive force be generated? I can't imagine what kind of structure would allow tensile and compressive forces to coexist

@NOHWHIREA for example imagine a C clamp on the end of a spoke, with some structure built inwards from the outer end of the C. That structure and the portion of the clamp that it rests on would be in compression

@NOHWHIREA Even simpler: in a hollow cylindric body submitted to pressure on the inner surface and zero pressure on the outer surface, the radial stress is always compressive, while the tangential is tensile (see Theory of Elasticity, S.Timoshenko, J.N. Goodier, McGraw-Hill, 1969, p. 71, accessible on https://archive.org/details/TheoryOfElasticityByTimoshenkoAndGoodier/Advance%20Mechanics%20Of%20Material_Arthurp%20%26%20boresi/ )
